# I want to split a column into 6 six columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

I have a dataset with around 1200 lines and 1 column, I want to split this data set into six columns which are named in the first line.

```
import polars as pl
import os

# Abrindo um arquivo CSV
data_raw = open('C:\\Users\\DESKTOP\\Documents\\Pedro Amorim\\dados_de_poço\\dado_campos\\dado_campos1.csv', 'r+')
data_raw = pl.DataFrame(data=data_raw)


#Separando as colunas do arquivo CSV
data_raw[['DEPTH','DT', 'GR', 'ILD', 'NPHI', 'RHOB']] = data_raw.split(' ', expand=True)


print(data_raw)
```

[Printscreen now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhFpW.png)

Comment: Please explain what the issue is. Does your code work but not as expected or are you getting an error message?

Comment: I'd recommend editing your csv file to replace all in-line whitespace with a delimiter, then `read_csv` will do this all for you.

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.split.html

Comment: Please add example data as well as expected output.